# Better way to get data from JSON with multiple objects

Tags: c#, json

first of all, I have to apologize for my English.

I'm trying to find a better/faster way to get some data from JSON where are multiple objects (100+). Is there any way to tell my code to automatically create those objects for me - Vayne, Jhin, .. objects.

```
    namespace App
{
    class championListConfig
    {
        //championId and championPoints are from another web 
        public async void getChampions(dynamic championId, dynamic championPoints)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseChampionList = await StatsProcessor.client.GetAsync("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.22.1/data/en_US/champion.json");
            string rawJSON = await responseChampionList.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            RootObject championList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rawJSON);
            int championIntId = championId;

            switch (championIntId)
            {
                case 67:
                    Console.WriteLine(championList.data.Vayne.name + "  " + championPoints);
                    break;
                case 202:
                    Console.WriteLine(championList.data.Jhin.name + "  " + championPoints);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Nothing");
                    break;
            }
        }   
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
    public class Data
    {
    public ChampionName Vayne { get; set; }
    public ChampionName Jhin { get; set; }
    }
public class ChampionName
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample JSON pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` is a dictionary of champion name (string) to champion info:

```
public class RootObject
{
    // ...
    public Dictionary<string, ChampionInfo> Data { get; set; }
}
public class ChampionInfo
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...
}

// ...
var champion = response.Data.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == championId);
if (champion != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(champion.Name + " " + championPoints);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nothing");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find the solution for last two days.. and it was that simple.